# Multitouch precision touchpad gestures in Firefox

Tags: windows-10, firefox, touchpad

Is there a way to enable multitouch swipe gestures for navigating through the browser history in Firefox when using a precision touchpad in Windows 10? I imagine it would work the same way as in Edge, i.e. two finger swipe left/right.

[This page](https://www.cryptlife.com/browsers/mac-like-swipe-back-and-forward-touchpad-on-browser-for-windows) tells me that a particular extension is all that is needed, but the link to it seems to suggest that it isn't available anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an extension that adds two finger swiping for navigating browser history: **SwipeToNavigate**. Tested and working on a Lenovo IdeaPad running Windows 10.

[Firefox Add-Ons page](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/swipetonavigate/) | [GitHub repo](https://github.com/totu/Swipe2Nav)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you're still looking for an answer, but just today when trying to get this working myself, I found a Reddit thread showing you can make it happen with a build in setting in Windows 10. It will be 3 or 4 finger swipe though.

Edited to add instructions in answer itself:

> Open the Windows 10 settings app and then go to Devices --> Touchpad. On the right under "Related Settings" go to "Advanced gesture configuration". Here you can define each swipe action individually. The ones you want are "Forward navigation" and "Backward navigation"

You can find the thread here: [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/thinkpad/comments/9qwkhc/touchpad_gestures_for_firefox/e8ea2hn/)

Hope this helps!